# app notifications disrupt Pandora volume

Tags: android, audio, notifications

Hoping someone can help with a weird bug: when our Android app posts a status bar notification  and the user's listening to Pandora, the volume drops for the notification (as expected) but then doesn't come back up until the next song.

This doesn't seem to happen with streaming apps other than Pandora, or with apps other than ours -- even though as far as I know our use of the notification APIs is standard. It's also restricted to certain devices: it doesn't happen on our Nexus 4 or Droid RAZR M, but we can reproduce it consistently on our Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2.

Any idea what's going on?

**EDIT**
As requested, some info on our BroadcastReceiver code. Initially it does a bunch of stuff with our DB via a ContentProvider, to grab the info to display in the notification. Once that's done:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_new_message)
        .setTicker(Html.fromHtml("<strong>" + senders[0] + "</strong> " + summaries[0]))
        .setContentInfo((messageCount > 1) ? Integer.toString(messageCount) : "").setAutoCancel(true); 

// Notification sound and vibration
if (prefs.getBoolean(PREF_SOUND, true)) {
    setupSound(builder);
}

// Blinky light
if (prefs.getBoolean(PREF_BLINK, true)) {
    setupLight(builder, LIGHT_COLOR);
}

Intent resultIntent;
TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

if (senders.length > 1) {
    String contentTitle = messageCount + " new messages";
    builder.setContentTitle(contentTitle);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    bigStyle.setBigContentTitle(contentTitle);

    HashSet<String> uniqueSenders = new HashSet<String>(senders.length);
    for (i = 0; i < senders.length; i++) {
        bigStyle.addLine(Html.fromHtml("<strong>" + senders[i] + "</strong> " + summaries[i]));
        uniqueSenders.add(senders[i]);
    }
    builder.setContentText(TextUtils.join(", ", uniqueSenders));
    builder.setStyle(bigStyle);

    resultIntent = new Intent(App.getContext(), ChatListActivity.class);
} else {
    builder.setContentTitle("Message from " + senders[0]);
    setLargeImage(context, lastCorrespondents, builder);

    builder.setContentText(summaries[0]);

    // Intent + back stack
    resultIntent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(MessageDbContract.KEY_CORRESPONDENTS, lastCorrespondents);
    taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatActivity.class);
}

resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_KEY_CALLER, getClass().getSimpleName());

// Finish configuring action
invokeNotificationManager(context, builder, resultIntent, taskStackBuilder, NOTIFICATION_ID_NEW_MESSAGES);
```

And the helper functions referenced above:

```
private void setLargeImage(Context context, String lastCorrespondents, NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
    // Set large image
    try {
        Uri imageUri = Util.getThumbnailUriForCorrespondents(context, lastCorrespondents);
        Bitmap largeImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        builder.setLargeIcon(largeImage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Util.log(this, "Encountered IOException when setting large icon for new message notification.");
    }
}

private void setupLight(NotificationCompat.Builder builder, int lightColor) {
    builder.setLights(lightColor, LIGHT_ON_DURATION, LIGHT_OFF_DURATION);
}

private void setupSound(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(uri);
    builder.setVibrate(VIBRATION_PATTERN);
}

private void invokeNotificationManager(Context context, NotificationCompat.Builder builder, Intent resultIntent,
        TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder, int notificationId) {
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Get notification manager, create notification, and notify.
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(App.NOTIFICATION_NEW_MESSAGE, notificationId, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: What code does your BroadcastReceiver launch?

Comment: Added code as requested.